# Serving Laravel public/ contents when all Laravel files are in the same server directory

Tags: security, laravel, server, .htaccess

I have a Laravel 8 project hosted at `xxx/laravel/` on an Apache server, where `xxx` is the domain. I want to serve the contents of `xxx/laravel/public/` when users access `xxx/laravel/`. However, I need to prevent access to other files at `xxx/laravel/`, e.g. `xxx/laravel/.env`.

Normally, I would host the project files in directory outside the web directory (e.g. `/home/projects/laravel` instead of `/var/www/html/laravel`). I would then create a symlink from `/home/projects/laravel/public` to `/var/www/html/laravel` so that files such as .env are not accessible.

However, I need to store all the project files in the same place: `/var/www/html/laravel`.

I have found a potential solution which involved:

- Copying `/var/www/html/laravel/public/.htaccess` to `/var/www/html/laravel/.htaccess`
- Editing the new `/var/www/html/laravel/.htaccess` by:

  - Rewriting URLs using `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravel/public/$1`
  - Using `server.php` instead of `index.php` in the last rule, `RewriteRule ^ server.php [L]`
  - (Additionally) removing the `-Indexes` option

I followed some guidance from a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28364496/laravel-5-remove-public-from-url) about using the existing `public/` `.htaccess`. However, I did not create another `index.php` from a copy of `server.php`, and I made the above changes to prevent access to files.

Here is the modified `/var/www/html/laravel/.htaccess` (changes shown in comments with 'CHANGED').

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        # CHANGED: remove -Indexes
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # CHANGED: rewrite URLs to xxx/laravel/public
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravel/public/$1

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    # CHANGED: use server.php instead of index.php
    RewriteRule ^ server.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I know that this may still not be an optimal way of doing things, but given that I cannot use the typical method involving a symlink, I am unsure.

Is this method secure and reliable?